# connecting android app to webserver using post method

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple android app in which I'm trying to connect my app to a webserver where I have a database named akshaynsit1_pathaniswaad and in that database I have a table named table1. In this table I have 3 columns id(int auto increment primary key),name(varchar(30)),addr varchar(30).I'm creating a simple signup page where user will add his name and address and this name and address will get saved to my webserver through post method.
My MainActivity.java is as follows

**package com.example.akshay007.sample;**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed1,ed2;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    public void insert(View view){
        String name = ed1.getText().toString();
        String add = ed2.getText().toString();

        insertToDatabase(name,add);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String name, String add){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramAddress = params[1];
                try{
                    String name = paramUsername;
                    String address = paramAddress;

                    String link="http://http://pathaniswaad.com/android_akshay/post.php";
                    String data  = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8");

                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                    wr.write( data );
                    wr.flush();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                //return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yo bro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                //textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
                //tv.setText("ya brah..");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, add);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml is as follows**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Merchant Signup"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml is as follows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.akshay007.sample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**my post.php script is as follows**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("65.50.265.181:336","jfjtyfyfhjfjdy","uitytityut67","akshaynsit1_pathaniswaad");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo"connection successful <br>";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"insert into table1 (name,addr) values ('$name','$address')");
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please help any kind of help would be appreciated!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: my app is not able to connect to webserver and  the data that user fill in the app is not getting stored in webserver.The problem is somewhere in the method insertToDatabase(String name, String add) of MainActivity.java

Comment: post your logcat....

Comment: do you want the entire logcat statements??

Answer (score 0):

If you do not already have this in your manifest file, add it before the `<application>` section:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, I have noticed that your link, in the code, is

```
http://http://pathaniswaad.com/android_akshay/post.php
```

Try changing it to

```
http://pathaniswaad.com/android_akshay/post.php
```

As the other user has also pointed out, you need the params appended.  There is a better way to do this using loopj HttpAsyncClient:

Add to your gradle build:

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Here is a class I created to use this with GitHub Jobs, you can modify it for your uses:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class AsyncRestClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jobs.github.com/positions";
    private static final String JSON_RESPONSE_APPEND = ".json";
    private static final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void getPositions(RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        get(JSON_RESPONSE_APPEND, params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

And here is a code snippet where I use this class:

```
    RequestParams params = jobRequested.getRequestParams();
    AsyncRestClient.getPositions(params, getPositionsResponseHandler);
```

You would need to write your own response handler.  If you want to see all the code, I have this project on GitHub (it is in active development), and you can see how I wrote the response handlers and callbacks for the responses:

https://github.com/JenniferVanderputten/GitHubJobs

Comment: I already have already added internet permission in my manifest file..........you can see the code above.

Comment: I updated the answer with another thing to try -- not sure if you get notification for answer edits, so I am adding this comment.

Answer (score 0):

TWO things NEED to be fixed:

1. your post url link looks incorrect:

   http://http://pathaniswaad.com/android_akshay/post.php

"http://" is used twice. change it to:

```
    http://pathaniswaad.com/android_akshay/post.php
```

2. you have forgotten to append the params to url:

   ```
   String data  = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
   data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8");

   link += "?"+data;  //add this line here

   URL url = new URL(link);
   ```

Fix these 2 and try again. You should also test you PHP by using a fabricated url directly into your browser. that way it will make sure that there is no issue in the PHP itself.

good luck.